# ASP.NET MVC 3 EF Code First - also use existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am in the process of writing a new web application. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Entity Framework code first. The database is automatically created and everything looks good so far.

However, we already have an existing database that holds details of all our current users and I want to be able to retrieve data from this database table in my new project. Is this possible using EF Code First and if so, how would I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

I have done the same a few months ago. You can map your Model to an existing Database.
Scott Guthrie has blogged about it. You can use the **Enity Framework Power Tools** to create your models from your existing Database.

#### More Information

- [Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)
- [Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to just map to existing database and use EF code first to automatically create a different database?

Comment: Yes but you need 2 Different `DbContext` for that. One for your existing db and one for the new automatically generated database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Have a look at Scott Gu's blog where he describes how to do it. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx